# How to recover disk and files after 10.04 boot failure?

Tags: 10.04, boot-failure, data-recovery

I have a 1TB HDD with four Windows XP partitions and a 120GB HDD with 10.04. While working in Ubuntu, due to delay and failure to shutdown, I switched off the system.

Next it failed to boot in Ubuntu and stopped at `initramfs`. After that, I tried to repair from the booting stage. By mistake instead of **hdd no** I used **partition no**. This damaged the Windows also.

Then Windows XP was reloaded and is running.

When I boot with 12.04, it is able to detect the 120GB HDD, but, it is unable to mount. I am unable to access the files.

I would like to revive the disk and recover files. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by finding your installer/live disk and mounting the drive. After mounting the drive run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to fix the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from an Ubuntu live cd and install boot-repair

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Using the boot-repait software you can restore your grub and login